# Subtree replacement in crossover

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, genetic-programming, crossover

I have a problem with a school project concerning genetic programming.

I'm using the subtree crossover method so I have to perform these steps:

1. Choose a random node (insertion point) from father tree.
2. Choose a random subtree from mother tree.
3. Replace the insertion point from father with subtree from mother.

I'm pretty sure that the 3rd point doesn't work in my code. I've tried several different aproaches to this problem ([Deep copying and swapping subtrees in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257679/deep-copying-and-swapping-subtrees-in-java) - this one too) but none of them seem to work.

They way I thought it would work was to create a new tree called "child" which would be a copy of the father tree, then using that tree find a random Node and then just replace that found node with a subtree (so de facto a node too) from the mother tree.

I've also tried searching the trees for a match, updating parents/children explicitly but everything point to the fact that it's either not a solution or I'm doing it wrong.

So I'm giving you the basic version of my code; every hint at what's wrong with my way of thinking is much appreciated.

**TreeNode.java**

```
public class TreeNode implements Iterable<TreeNode> {

    protected Data data;
    protected TreeNode parent;
    protected List<TreeNode> children;
    public static Long IDENTIFIER = 0L;

    public double getValue(double xValue) {
        return 0;
    };

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return parent == null;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return children.size() == 0;
    }

    protected List<TreeNode> elementsIndex;

    public TreeNode(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        this.elementsIndex = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        this.elementsIndex.add(this);
        this.data.setId(IDENTIFIER++);
        if (this instanceof Function)
            this.data.setChildAmount(2);
        else if (this instanceof Terminal)
            this.data.setChildAmount(0);
    }

    public TreeNode(Data data, TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        this.elementsIndex = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        this.elementsIndex.add(this);
        this.data.setId(IDENTIFIER++);
        if(this instanceof Function)
            this.data.setChildAmount(2);
        else if (this instanceof Terminal)
            this.data.setChildAmount(0);

    }

    public TreeNode copyTree() {
        TreeNode clone;
        switch (this.getData().getType()) {
        case 10:
            clone = new Add(new Data(10));
            break;
        case 11:
            clone = new Substract(new Data(11));
            break;
        case 12:
            clone = new Multiply(new Data(12));
            break;
        case 13:
            clone = new Divide(new Data(13));
            break;
        case 20:
            clone = new Constant(new Data(20));
            break;
        case 21:
            clone = new Variable(new Data(21));
            break;
        default:
            return null;
        }
        clone.setData(this.getData());
        clone.setParent(this.getParent());
        clone.setChildren(this.getChildren());
        clone.setElementsIndex(this.getElementsIndex());

        return clone;

    }

    public TreeNode copy() {
        return copyWithParent(parent);
    }

    public TreeNode copyWithParent(TreeNode parent) {

        TreeNode out;

        switch (this.getData().getType()) {
        case 10:
            out = new Add(new Data(10), parent);
            break;
        case 11:
            out = new Substract(new Data(11), parent);
            break;
        case 12:
            out = new Multiply(new Data(12), parent);
            break;
        case 13:
            out = new Divide(new Data(13), parent);
            break;
        case 20:
            out = new Constant(new Data(20), parent);
            break;
        case 21:
            out = new Variable(new Data(21), parent);
            break;
        default:
            return null;
        }

        if (!this.getChildren().isEmpty()) {

            if (this.getChildren().get(0) != null) {
                out.getChildren().get(0).copyWithParent(out);
            }

            if (this.getChildren().get(1) != null) {
                out.getChildren().get(1).copyWithParent(out);
            }
        }

        return out;
    }

    public TreeNode addChild(Data childType, TreeNode child) {
        TreeNode childNode = child.copyTree();
        childNode.parent = this;
        this.children.add(childNode);
        this.registerChildForSearch(childNode);
        return childNode;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        if (this.isRoot())
            return 0;
        else
            return parent.getLevel() + 1;
    }

    private TreeNode selectSubClass(Data data) {
        switch (data.getType()) {
        case 10:
            return new Add(data);
        case 11:
            return new Substract(data);
        case 12:
            return new Multiply(data);
        case 13:
            return new Divide(data);
        case 20:
            return new Constant(data);
        case 21:
            return new Variable(data);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void registerChildForSearch(TreeNode node) {
        elementsIndex.add(node);
        if (parent != null)
            parent.registerChildForSearch(node);
    }

    public TreeNode findTreeNode(Comparable<Data> cmp) {
        for (TreeNode element : this.elementsIndex) {
            Data elData = element.data;
            if (cmp.compareTo(elData) == 0)
                return element;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ((data != null) ? this.getData().toString() : "[null]");
    }

    public String printFunction() {
        String left;
        String right;
        if (!this.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            left = this.getChildren().get(0).printFunction();
            right = this.getChildren().get(1).printFunction();
            return "(" + left + ")" + this.getData().toString() + "(" + right + ")";
        }
        return this.getData().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<TreeNode> iterator() {
        TreeNodeIter iter = new TreeNodeIter(this);
        return iter;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<TreeNode> children) {
        this.children.addAll(children);
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getElementsIndex() {
        return elementsIndex;
    }

    public void setElementsIndex(List<TreeNode> elementsIndex) {
        this.elementsIndex = elementsIndex;
    }

    // Ghost Method - should be always overriden
    public TreeNode chooseRandomChild() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TreeNode other = (TreeNode) obj;
        if (children == null) {
            if (other.children != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!children.equals(other.children))
            return false;
        if (data == null) {
            if (other.data != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
            return false;
        if (elementsIndex == null) {
            if (other.elementsIndex != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!elementsIndex.equals(other.elementsIndex))
            return false;
        if (parent == null) {
            if (other.parent != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!parent.equals(other.parent))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Used methods from Chromosome.java**

```
    public TreeNode chooseRandomNode(TreeNode remainingSubtree, boolean isInitial, int chosenMaxLevel,
            int currentLevel) {
        int maxLevel = 0;
        TreeNode chosenNode = remainingSubtree.getParent();
        if (isInitial) {
            // if method was called on tree with single node
            if (remainingSubtree instanceof Terminal)
                return remainingSubtree;
            this.treeHeight = countTreeDepth(this.getSchema());
            Random random = new Random();
            maxLevel = random.nextInt(treeHeight) + 1;
        } else {
            maxLevel = chosenMaxLevel;
        }

        if (currentLevel < maxLevel) {
            TreeNode temp = remainingSubtree.chooseRandomChild();
            if (temp instanceof Function)
                chosenNode = chooseRandomNode(temp, false, maxLevel, currentLevel + 1);
            else
                chosenNode = temp;
        }

        return chosenNode;
    }

    public int countTreeDepth(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.equals(null)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (!node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            int leftChild = countTreeDepth(node.getChildren().get(0));
            int rightChild = countTreeDepth(node.getChildren().get(1));
            return (leftChild > rightChild) ? leftChild + 1 : rightChild + 1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

**Crossover method from Genetics.java**

```
public static Chromosome crossover(Chromosome father, Chromosome mother) {
    TreeNode child = father.getSchema();

    TreeNode insertionPoint = father.chooseRandomNode(child, true, 0, 0);
    TreeNode temp = insertionPoint.copy();

    TreeNode motherSubTree = mother.chooseRandomNode(mother.getSchema(), true, 0, 0);

    insertionPoint = motherSubTree.copyTree();

    Chromosome offspring = new Chromosome();
    offspring.copyIndividual(child);

    return offspring;
}
```

Here's a link to our github repo with whole project: https://github.com/Nevaan/symbolic_regression

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is too late for your school project, but posting answer in case it helps anyone with a similar problem:

The issue is in the CrossOver method:   The "child" variable starts as a copy of the "father" schema.  Then, you create the variable "insertionPoint"  pointing at the Subtree you wish to replace.   But then, when you assign the "motherSubtree" to that variable,  you are actually just replacing your local varaible in the method, not the subtree in the object.  You actually need to "reinsert"  a copy of the "motherSubtree" in the new Tree after it has been created.